# homebrew install of octave dependency tbb and env vars CC and CXX

Tags: environment-variables, osx-mountain-lion, octave, homebrew, tbb

I'm trying to install octave on my new macbook pro (OSX10.8.4) using homebrew. It balks on the installation of the dependency package tbb, so for the purposes of this question what I'm trying to install is tbb.

Here's the short version:

```
>>> brew install tbb 
 ==> Downloading   
http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/sites/default/files/software_releases/source/tbb41_20130613oss_src.tgz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/tbb-4.1u4.tgz
==> make tbb_build_prefix=BUILDPREFIX CONLY=gcc-4.8 CPLUS=g++-4.8 arch=intel64
make[1]: *** [concurrent_queue.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [concurrent_vector.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [dynamic_link.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [itt_notify.o] Error 1
make: *** [tbb] Error 2
```

The verbose gist is at https://gist.github.com/mwbinger/6502745

It was suggested on the homebrew forum https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/22424
that gcc-4.8 and g++-4.8 are not compatible with tbb, so I tried changing the env vars 
CC and CXX. After doing so, I get identical errors as above. In particular, homebrew still seems to be finding only versions 4.8, not 4.2. In particular, the vars CONLY and CPLUS in the make command are not finding the right compilers.
But truthfully I'm am a bit lost. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 && export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.2
echo $CXX
==> /usr/bin/g++-4.2
echo $CC
==> /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Even after doing the above I get the same errors as above when running `brew install tbb`.

Any way I can get tbb (and thus octave) installed on my mac would be great, preferably through homebrew since that's what I've been using and from what I've read a different package manager might cause conflicts with other packages due to different path settings.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been resolved... it required an internal fix to homebrew's compiler priorities. Details here: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/22424

So hopefully nobody will run into the same problems. If so, be sure to run `brew update` and `brew upgrade` to pull the fixes. `brew install tbb` and `brew install octave` now work perfectly after doing that.